# when i change data and use dataTable.fnDraw(), dataTable return 1 page

Tags: jquery, datatables

I change data not in 1st page,but use function:"dataTable.fnDraw()" always return 1 page?
how can i record page and return now page!

Comment: could you create jsfiddle or codepen to debug easily?

Comment: Please add some code or a JSfiddle to find out your problem correctly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `dataTable.fnDraw()`, try the following:

```
var pageIndex = dataTable.fnPagingInfo().iPage;

// Change table data here.

dataTable.fnPageChange(pageIndex);
```

The call to `fnPagingInfo().iPage` gets the current page index, while the call to `fnPageChange()` will redraw the table. But in order to use `.fnPagingInfo()`, you must include the [fnPagingInfo plug-in](https://datatables.net/plug-ins/api/fnPagingInfo).